# Using constants in XML

Tags: xml, constants

I have my XML code as below and I need to call the file thats stored in the location ../../tasks/sql/OPI. The example below doesnt seem to work where I say $SQL_PATH/OPI.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StringTable term="&sep;">
<String key="$SQL_PATH">../../tasks/sql</String>
</StringTable>

<Task id="DATA">
<Wrapper type="com.xxx.SQLRunnerWrapper">
<Input iName="SQLFilePath">$SQL_PATH/OPI</Input>
</Wrapper>
</Task>
```

Can I get some help please? thanks

Answer (score 1):

XML is just data. When you say this "doesn't work", then you can only mean that you expect some piece of software to interpret this data in some particular way. You don't say what you were doing, or what piece of software you were using to do it, or how you expected that software to behave. Which makes it rather difficult to give you any help, to say the least.

What you have shown us isn't even well-formed XML because you can't refer to an entity `&sep;` without a declaration of that entity in your DTD.